# Can't find the red door at level 12

Tags: vim-adventures

I've managed to get 2 red keys on level 12. Now I understand that I should open a red gate somewhere, but I cannot find it!

Where is the red gate? I've roamed everywhere without any luck!

Answer (score 1):

There are two red doors.  Using your browser's "zoom" function can help you spot them.

[image: Two red doors southeast of the Level 12 entry.]
To get to those doors, from the Level 12 entry, go through these puzzles:

- (right, up) Buffy the Vampire Slayer
- (up) These are not the droids you are looking for
- (right, down) Position: absolute

[image: Two red doors south of the "These are not the droids" and "position: absolute" puzzles.]

Happy Vim Adventuring!